# Deny acces to all Internet hosts except several

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, I want to restrict access to Internet to all programs and processes. I also want to allow several hosts after that. I was trying to do that with `iptables`, but I could figure out all its arguments and copypasted mostly. Can someone please give me, for example, two commands with `iptables`: first one denied access to Internet, second one allow acces to specified host, like `www.google.com`?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems to be the same problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/218707/iptables-rules-to-allow-http-traffic-to-one-domain-only

Comment: That seems to solve my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try a user friendly GUI frontend:

```
sudo apt-get install gufw
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case I cannot use gui elements and moreover I should better do everything with less packages, using native Linux tools.